# Error when installing OpenCV on RaspberryPi 3

Tags: raspbian

The error message I am getting is:

```
[40%] Built target opencv_video
Makefile:137: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have looked around, and people said that it might work with `cmake -D WITH_IPP=OFF`, but it does not seem to work.

Anyone that has succeeded in installing OpenCV on RasPi3, can you help me out? Or, I would like to know if RasPi3 is not compatible, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue when I went to install OpenCV 2.4.9 on my Raspberry Pi 3. Interestingly enough, OpenCV 3.0.0 worked okay, so if you were installing that then I can't help. For me, disabling ffmpeg in the cmake options fixed the issue. Here is the command I used:

```
cmake ../ -DWITH_FFMPEG=OFF
```

Followed by the standard `make` and `install`.

Edit: also, I had tried installing ffmpeg in the past and installing OpenCV 2.4.9. This also failed. It is possible I messed up the ffmpeg install because I only tried it once. If you need ffmpeg, you may have to sort out some deeper issue yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Using

```
cmake ../ -DWITH_FFMPEG=OFF 
make
make install
```

works for me !

Comment: How does this differ from the [answer provided by Connor](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44331/error-when-installing-opencv-on-raspberrypi-3#answer-44482)?